# How should I do to send data between two jsp with a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to display something from one jsp page in another jsp page by clicking a button. I did it using `request.setAttribute request.getAttribute` but it doesn't work for me, for some reason the variable I send is null or the page is blank.

Comment: You have to add more details about what exactly you're doing

Comment: Sure https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24435614 I asked two questions previously but no one answered them therefore I thought I should ask a shorter question

Comment: Added a note to your original post. Check if that helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send data between two jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58606075/how-do-i-send-data-between-two-jsp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your original question : When you are doing setAttribute(), its scope is limited to the request when the main page is loading and hence will not be available on the next page as it will be a new request.

```
<%Object product=ptp;
                   request.setAttribute("purchase", ptp.getId());
          %>
```

What you can do is, submit this value in URL param as GET or in a form (get/ post) to fetch it on next JSP using request.getParameter().

Or you can use session scope by session.setAttribute()

Hope it helps

Comment: I am going to test it with url param, I alredy tried with session and it doesn't work either. Thank you for the idea

Comment: Yes, just make sure you put the input in a valid form and submit it to another JSP. I noticed 2 forms in your JSP and 2nd form has a two buttons 'add to cart' and 'Add To Cart'. Make sure when you use it, value is actually submitted. Also I don't see a reason why session scope not working unless value is there while you set it up. Anyways... good luck :)

Comment: Yes it worked by using a from in the end, but I also had to use a Hashmap in which I put the requested parameter, for some reason it didn't work with the Object.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

you can pass the variables through request scope or session scope.

```
request.setAttribute("variable name","value of its");

session.setAttribute("variable name","value");
```

Here a detailed exmple 
http://www.jsptut.com/sessions.jsp